# Hyperlink without underline in deleted answer's post notice

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, post-notices

Recently I deleted one of my [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340685/312043) (10k+ users only). After it deleted, there is a inconsistency with the hyperlink in the post notices.

The deleted question link contains a hyperlink, whereas the deleted answer link doesn't contain the hyperlink. Both are linked by `<a href=`.

The underline in the answer section is intentionally removed or it is a bug?

Question section:

[image: Question section]

Answer section:

[image: Answer section]

Comment: For questions, the notice banner is *inside* `div.post-text`, so a CSS rule matching `.post-text a` setting underlines is applied to question notices. However, for answers, the banner is *outside* such a container, and the global `text-decoration: none` (a bare matcher `a`) is applied to links in answer notices.

Indeed a bug if I must say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed. All links within post notices should now be shown once more.